# JSON.stringify replace pluses with spaces

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I use AJAX and send string **someString** to php-handler

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
var someString = 'Foo+Bar';
var params = 'operation='+operation+'&json='+JSON.stringify(someString);
xmlHttp.send(params);
```

If someString contains '+' it replacing with space. As I could read, it is normal work of JSON.stringify, but **how can I get pluses (using JS only)**?

The second question is what other symbols replacing by JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That has nothing to do with `JSON.stringify`.

The conversion of `+` to a  is done by the URL parser on the server. A `+` is one of the ways you can represent a space in a URL (the other being `%20`).

To convert text to make it safe to insert into a URL, use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question... URL parser works even I use **xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true)**, not GET?

Comment: @ilyatom — A URL is a URL, so yes. (And if you mean that you would send the data in the request body, then the default encoding that servers use to parse posted data is the same as URLs).